# != doesn't act as it should in VS code editor

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, irb

```
command = " "

while command != "bye"
  puts command
  command = gets.chomp
end 

puts "Come again soon!"
```

This while loop doesn't act as it should in VS code editor. The loop runs continually even when the exit command is entered. Tested != in irb and it works are it should. Is this a stange aspect of the editor. It makes me want to tear my hair out! SOS

Comment: Just curious: what does it print when you type 'bye'?

Comment: It just prints "bye" so it is continues in the loop when it should be exiting and saying "Come again soon"

Comment: It seems that \r or \n or other new-line character is added to the end of string and not chomped. Could you replace ```puts command``` with ```puts command, command.length``` to test this version?

Comment: when using [command.length] it returns an extra char length then it should ie hello returns 6 instead of 5 Eh? Why would this be happening?

Comment: Well, it's VisualStudio, so I assume you're on Windows. It has a special symbol for new line, different from Unix-systems. However it must be processed normally by ```chomp```, not sure why VS terminal does it differently. Anyway, ```command[-1].ord``` call will tell you ASCII code of that symbol and you can google what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using #strip instead of #chomp.  It will remove leading AND trailing whitespace.

From [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip)

`"    hello    ".strip   #=> "hello"`

`"\tgoodbye\r\n".strip   #=> "goodbye"`